# Shifting commits from one branch on top of other branch

Tags: git, github, rebase, branching-and-merging

I have two branches X and Y.Some commits are common in both branches, but for those commits which are present in branch X and not present in branch Y. I want those commits to be committed on top of branch Y. What are git commands for this ?

Comment: Does `git rebase [remote] X` on branch Y work?

Comment: @Kevin `git rebase` won't commit X on top of Y, but rather replaying X's commits on Y and then apply Y's commits

Answer (score 0):

Use `git cherry-pick <commit-hash>` from branch Y, while replacing the `<commit-hash>` with the SHA hash of the commit from X.

If you want to cherry-pick multiple commits use `git cherry-pick A..B` where A is an older commit then B. This will copy all the commit after A up to B, inclusive. To include A commit in the cherry-picking use `git cherry-pick A^..B`.